# How to read two files and add or subtract balance in field from another file field

Tags: awk

File 1:

```
Joes Garage                             
Utility Muffin Research Kitchen         
Apple
```

File 2:

```
Joes Garage $100.24 payment 
PipCo $20.13 due    
Utility Muffin Research Kitchen $2.44 due       
Uber $50.33 payment 
Microsoft $120.33 due   
Apple $220.33 payment
uber $40.44 payment
PipCo $40.99 payment
Apple $100.44 due
```

I want only print a read from business name listed in file 1 and calculate their balance.
for example, a business may have different transactions. therefore, print that business with only one balance. 
Thanks

Comment: Expected output? Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not sure if I interpret the question correctly.

Here is a version that cheats and uses `sed` to pre-format `file2` so we can directly access the relevant fields in `awk`. If you want to do all the work just using `awk` you will probably need to use some sort of loop and/or `split`.

```
$ cat t.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=":" }
NR==FNR {
        switch($3) {
            case "payment":
                balance[$1] += $2
                break
            case "due":
                balance[$1] -= $2
                break
        }
        next
    }
{
    if ($0 in balance)
        printf "%s %s$%0.2f\n",
            $0,
            balance[$0] >= 0 ? "" : "-",
            sqrt(balance[$0]*balance[$0])
}
```

.

```
$ ./t.awk <(sed -e 's# \$#:#' -e 's#[[:digit:]] #:#' file2.txt) file1.txt
Joes Garage $100.20
Utility Muffin Research Kitchen -$2.40
Apple $119.90
```

If this is homework which requires you to only use `awk` this should be able to serve as a starting point without doing all the work for you.